# Proof of $|P(X\in C)-P(Y \in C)|\leq P(X \neq Y)$ where $C\subset \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: probability

This result came up as part of a proof of the convergence rate of the Poisson approximation to the binomial.

The author gives no proof of it, but it didn't seem obvious to me. I attempted to prove it myself. My results are as follows:

---

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two non-negative, discrete random variables, possibly correlated.

Let $C\subset \mathbb{N}$ and $A:=\{X\in C\},B:=\{Y\in C\}$

**Prove**: $|P(X\in C)-P(Y \in C)|\leq P(X \neq Y)$

In order to get the difference of two probabilities, I started with the following event probability calculation (note: I am using $\neg$ to signify complementation:

$P(A\cup \neg B)=P(A)+(1-P(B))-P(A\cap \neg B)$

Now, I used DeMorgan's law to re-write the LHS, and I simplified the RHS:

$P(\neg(\neg A\cap B))=P(A)-P(B)+1-P(A\cap \neg B)$

The LHS can be rewritten as a complement:

$1-P(\neg A\cap B)=P(A)-P(B)+1-P(A\cap \neg B)$

Simplifying and rearranging the terms to get intersections on one side, I get:

$P(A\cap \neg B)-P(\neg A\cap B)=P(A)-P(B)$

The LHS is the complement of another event:$\{(A\cap \neg B)\cup (\neg A\cap B)\}$, re-writing we get:

$1-P(\{(A\cap \neg B)\cup (\neg A\cap B)\})=P(A)-P(B)$ Since $\{(A\cap \neg B)\cup (\neg A\cap B)\}$ is the union of two disjoint events.

Now, I think up to this point I've not made any errors. Here's the dicier part:

The event $\{(A\cap \neg B)\cup (\neg A\cap B)\}$ appears to be a subset of $\{X\neq Y\}$, in which case:

$P(\{(A\cap \neg B)\cup (\neg A\cap B)\})\leq P(\{X\neq Y\}) \implies P(A\cap \neg B)+P(\neg A\cap B)\leq P(\{X\neq Y\})$

Noting that probabilities are always positive, I can deduce:

$P(A\cap \neg B)-P(\neg A\cap B)\leq P(A\cap \neg B)+P(\neg A\cap B)\leq P(\{X\neq Y\})$

Hence:

$P(\{X\neq Y\}) \geq P(A\cap \neg B)-P(\neg A\cap B) = P(A)-P(B)$

Now, the RHS does not need to be positive, but $P(X \neq Y)\geq 0$ so taking absolute values of both sides, I get:

$P(\{X\neq Y\}) \geq |P(A)-P(B)|$

$\square$???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointwise inequality $$|\mathbf 1_{x\in C}-\mathbf 1_{y\in C}|\leqslant\mathbf 1_{x\ne y}$$ implies that $$|P(X\in C)-P(Y\in C)|=|E(\mathbf 1_{X\in C}-\mathbf 1_{Y\in C})|\leqslant E(|\mathbf 1_{X\in C}-\mathbf 1_{Y\in C}|)\leqslant E(\mathbf 1_{X\ne Y})=P(X\ne Y).$$

Comment: Awesome. Thanks - that is super elegant. Did my far-more-tortured proof also work?

Comment: It seems to go astray at "The LHS is the complement of another event".

Comment: Thanks! What I really could have done at that point was just jump to "we can deduce"...since I really didn't need the foray into the "complementary" event. Although, your answer is much more insightful.

Comment: $$P(A\cap \neg B)-P(\neg A\cap B)\ne 1-P((A\cap \neg B)\cup (\neg A\cap B))$$

Comment: Yep, I realized that..I also realized it was an irrelevant tangent. I really only relied on $P(A\cap \neg B)-P(\neg A\cap B)\leq P(A\cap \neg B)+P(\neg A\cap B)\leq P(\{X\neq Y\})$

Comment: Larer on, you prove that $P(\{X\neq Y\}) \geq P(A)-P(B)$. This does not imply $P(\{X\neq Y\}) \geq |P(A)-P(B)|$.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for your patience.